# Android EditText with hardware keyboard only

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to use an EditText for the input from Barcode Scanners.

The Barcode Scanner acts like a physical Keyboard.

1. I scan a Barcode
2. It types the Barcode like an external Keyboard with a **enter** at the end

I have an EditText which should always be focused but never show the
software keyboard. I don't want to deactivate the Keyboard completely because it's needed in the same Class on a different EditText.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/barcodeText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
             >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then use TextChange Listener for your Edittext. Like this

```
  editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
  editText.requestFocus();
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
                  //  Your action
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this property

```
android:inputType="none"
```